# Is there any Google Cardboard Magnetic sensor trigger in Swift class examples?

Tags: swift, virtual-reality

Didn't find any examples of how to trigger the magnetic sensor using Swift online, so I'm posting an example here, since I created one myself.

This is tested on iPhone 6.

Comment: Thanks for your submission! Please formulate your mission statement as a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple trigger class that I wrote. It seems to be working quite well. Listener for the magnet data.

Usage:

```
let magnetListener = VRMagnetSensor()
magnetListener.callback = { type in
    // will print MAGNETIC SENSOR REPORTED onPress
    print("MAGNETIC SENSOR REPORTED \(type)")
}
```

And the class — VRMagnetSensor.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

public class VRMagnetSensor  {

    let manager = CMMotionManager()
    var previousMagnetData = ( x:0.0, y:0.0, z:0.0 )
    var callback:((type:String) ->())?

    init() {

        if manager.magnetometerAvailable && !manager.magnetometerActive {

            let sensorInterval = NSTimeInterval(0.5)
            manager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = sensorInterval
            manager.startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {
                (data, error) in

                let field = data!.magneticField

                print("MAGNETIC DATA x \(field.x)   y \(field.y)   z \(field.z)")

                if(field.x < self.previousMagnetData.x-30 && self.previousMagnetData.x != -0.0) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.callback!(type:"onPress")
                    }
                }
                self.previousMagnetData = ( x:field.x, y:field.y, z:field.z )
            })
        }
    }
}
```